# Width of controls inside listbox not changing after orientation change

Tags: xaml, layout, windows-phone-7.1, device-orientation

I have a grid inside stackpanel which is inside a listbox.
This grid has a few control elements like rectangles and textblocks.
They stretch to the entire width in portrait but not in landscape.

[Snapshot of emulator](http://techcrank.com/adityamoghe/Image.png)

This is the XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="PassList" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Grid Name="StackPanelWidth" Width="{Binding ElementName=PassList, Path=ActualWidth}">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=StackPanelWidth, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Rectangle Fill="White"
                                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                   RadiusX="10"
                                                   RadiusY="10"
                                                   />

                                        <Rectangle Fill="White"
                                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                   Margin="0,10,0,0"
                                                   />

                                        <Rectangle Fill="DarkGray"
                                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                                   Height="1"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                                   />

                                        <TextBlock Name="Country"
                                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                   Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   Text="{Binding Country}"
                                                   Foreground="Black"
                                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                                   />


                                        .............
                                        .............

                                    </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

Is there any thing wrong with my code?
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

why are you doing this?

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
  <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/> 
  <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=StackPanelWidth, Path=ActualWidth}"/> 
  <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/> 
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

Here you are somehow specifying the width because of which its not resizing.

Also the stackpanel will automatically adjust to its child width, so no need to specify binding if thats what you were trying to do.